# How to parse an image file as a QR Code in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: c#, image-processing, blazor, qr-code, blazor-webassembly

I have found many solutions that solve the other way around(QR Code generation) and some other that do only live QR Code scanning. But I'm looking for simple parsing of `IBrowserFile` to a QR Code `string`, the file is an image file, could be from a smartphone or from the snipping tool on the desktop.

I am down to even use external JS libraries if necessary, but there must be a guide on how to pass the required data correctly(between Blazor WebAssembly and JS).

Comment: "simple parsing" and "QR" don't correlate in my book - have you *seen* what's involved in reading a QR code?

Comment: sorry, what I meant is more of a way to find a match between Blazor and any js library that does already do the heavy lifting of taking the picture and if there's a code, spit it out.

Comment: Soo, you're after recommendation of a library?

Comment: @CaiusJard more of a guide that integrates well with Blazor